# Magento 1.4.1.1 Database

Tags: magento

I have the database backup from magento 1.4.1.1. Now I want to import it to Magento v1.7.0.2.

Does it work with next Magento versions? Are there any technical issues from using it this way?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the database from the backup
2. Add 1.7.0.2 to your webserver filesystem
3. Create/copy the local.xml file from the 1.4.1.1 install, pointing it to the new database.
4. Magento will run through any necessary upgrade scripts when you load any page
5. Profit